# How do I fix this Godot Android Debug Error?

Tags: android, debugging, export, apk, godot

When I try to run remote debugging, I run into this error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I tried installing the export template to that location, and I've tried moving the export to a different folder.

Comment: The screen shot mainly contains text, in such cases please always include that text in text for into your question.